# I'm trying to use ExpandableListView with a custom adapter, but cannot get anything to display

Tags: java, android, hashmap, expandablelistview

I am trying to use an ExpandableListView [using this tutorial](http://www.101apps.co.za/index.php/articles/expandable-lists.html) to display physical constants and their info.  I have made layouts for the child, the parent, and the activity I would like the list to display in.  My data is stored in a HashMap in the MyDataProvider class.  I believe that all of this is ok and should work.

The part I think is causing the problem is the Adapter, which I wrote myself and included below.  The problem is that when I go to this activity, the app does not crash, but just displays an entirely blank white screen.  I also looked at [this tutorial](http://www.learn-android-easily.com/2013/07/android-expandablelistview-example.html) if that informs anyone better.

Here is my adapter:

```
package com.gmd.referenceapplication;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 * Created by gmd on 6/13/2016.
 */
public class MyCustomAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private HashMap<String,ListViewItem> constantsHashMap;
    private List<String> constantList;

    public MyCustomAdapter(Context context, HashMap<String, ListViewItem> hashMap, List<String> list){

        constantsHashMap = hashMap;
        this.context = context;
        this.constantList = list;

    }



    public View getChildView(int groupPosition,
                             int childPosition,
                             boolean isLastChild,View convertView, ViewGroup parent)  {
        String childTitle = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition).toString();
        if(convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.child_layout, parent, false);
        }
        TextView childTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewChild);
        childTextView.setText(childTitle);
        return convertView;


    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public String getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return constantList.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return constantsHashMap.get(this.constantList.get(groupPosition));
                }


    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        String groupTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater =
                    (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.parent_layout, parent, false);
        }
        TextView parentTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewParent);
        parentTextView.setText(groupTitle);
        return convertView;
        }
    }
```

It seems like it may also be useful if I include the class where I am trying to display the list here:

```
package com.gmd.referenceapplication;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.gmd.referenceapplication.R;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class CommonConstants extends AppCompatActivity {
    View view;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_common_constants);


        MyDataProvider dp = new MyDataProvider();

        ExpandableListView view;
        view = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.expandableList);
        HashMap constantsHashMap;
        constantsHashMap = dp.getCommonMap();
        ArrayList constantsHashMapKeys = new ArrayList<String>(constantsHashMap.keySet());

        MyCustomAdapter adapter = new MyCustomAdapter(this, constantsHashMap, constantsHashMapKeys);
        view.setAdapter(adapter);










    }
}
```

I've done quite a bit of research on this and I'm still not sure what I'm doing wrong, so I would appreciate any and all help. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are returning 0 in group and child counts. This count is used to render groups and their children. Try this

```
@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return this.constantList.size();
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    return 1; // Looks like you have only one child in each group, change this if not
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should provide the right number of groups and children instead of 0.

```
@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    return 0;
}
```